How to construct the density matrix for the BCS wavefunction: $2 \times 2$ or $4 \times 4$?

Question Body:
In BCS theory, the ground state wavefunction for superconductivity is often written as:$
\Psi_{\text{BCS}} = \prod_{k} \left( u_k |00\rangle_k + v_k |11\rangle_k \right),
$
where$ |00\rangle_k$ represents the vacuum state for the momentum mode$ k$ (no particles), and $ |11\rangle_k$ represents a Cooper pair state (two fermions). Here,$ u_k$ and$ v_k$ are the coherence factors that satisfy $ |u_k|^2 + |v_k|^2 = 1$.
I would like to construct the density matrix corresponding to this wavefunction. My question is:

Should the density matrix be $ 2 \times 2 $ or $ 4 \times 4 $? I understand that we have only two basis states $( |00\rangle $ and $ |11\rangle $), but given that we are dealing with fermions and potentially more degrees of freedom (like spin), is it correct to use a larger matrix?

Could someone clarify how the dimensionality of the density matrix corresponds to the BCS wavefunction? Should we consider all possible configurations, or is there a simplified version?



It is not clear what density matrix you want to construct. Do you mean something like $\hat{\rho}k = \mbox{Tr}{k'\neq k} \Psi_{BCS}\cdot\Psi_{BCS}^\dagger$ or something else?

@Gec, I am currently working on constructing the density matrix for a Cooper pair. Since a Cooper pair consists of two fermions, each having two degrees of freedom (spin-up and spin-down), the natural setup leads to a 4×4 matrix representation. However, considering that the only permissible basis states for a Cooper pair are ∣00⟩ and ∣11⟩, would this restriction imply that the density matrix can be reduced to a 2×2 form in this specific basis?
